# Match only the value of ticket and not the value of myticket

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex which match the value just after the string "ticket="
The current regex used for that is

```
(?<=ticket=)[0-9]+
```

We had used positive lookbehind for this usecase.
How can we exclude a particular pre string before the current expression.
For eg:
If my string is

```
number of ticket=00000000001 
but number of myticket=10000000
I also have the number of my sistersticket=9999
```

This regex will have 3 matches as follows
[image: Regex matched response]

But how can I exclude the value of "myticket="?
Which means I only need 2 matches

```
00000000001
9999
```

Or in other words, I don't want to match if my string starts with "myticket="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a nested negative lookbehind asserting not `my` before `ticket`

```
(?<=(?<!\bmy)ticket=)[0-9]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZkzz8/1)

Another option using a capture group:

```
ticket=(?<!\bmyticket=)([0-9]+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9CjAWF/1)

Or with and a negative lookahead:

```
\b(?!my)\w*ticket=([0-9]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ltlWU3/1)

Comment: It works. 
Have a questions. Does this affect the performance of matcher.?

Comment: Regarding the performance of the regex, 
the more steps a regex needs to find a match, the slower the performance is. 
So it depends on your input string. And I does not mean this will cause a catastrophic backtracking

Comment: @VyshakPuthusseri Looking at the amount of steps on regex101 selecting pcre (note that this is a different flavor) this pattern with the capture group `ticket=(?<!\bmyticket=)([0-9]+)\b` seems to take the least amount of steps. But if you are looking for the fastest pattern, you can benchmark it to get a realistic estimate for different texts (like longer texts or different number occurrences of the word ticket in it)

Comment: My input data will be large and the regex I am using will be a combination of many lookbehinds and the regex given in the question is one among them. 
Right now, the regex engine was able to complete the matching in approximately 700ms.

Comment: @VyshakPuthusseri What does the full regex look like? Can you use capture groups to after process it, or do you only want to get the direct matches?

Comment: Full regex will be multiple positive lookbehings
For eg: just adding one more part
(?<=nginxid)|(?<=ticket)=[0-9]+
And more expressions will be used.

Comment: I was using this regex to replace the matched content,
Which means, I will use this matched content and will use the java.util.regex.Pattern.replaceAll() method to mask those ids.
Does this approach is wrong.
Or is there any better way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
(?<=[^my]ticket=)[0-9]+
```

Comment: But that would also not match `thatismyticket=10000000`